# Java Result Set is not working with pre-scripted SQL

Tags: java, sql, set, resultset

My Java program will not show or work with the SQL values that have already been put into the table prior to working with it in Eclipse.

What I mean is that I can add values to the table and it will tell me if I am adding the same values again, however it will lock up when I am trying to use a value that was already on the table that I put in through SQL.

I am at a loss for words and I can not understand why this is happening. I just need it to tell me that the value exists for the values that were already there. Here is my code:

```
public void addCourse(Statement st){   //**********This function adds a course to the database.
        String courseCode, courseTitle;
        int entriesChanged;   


        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a course code you would like to add: ");
            courseCode = scan.next().toUpperCase();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Course where code = '" + courseCode + "'");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("This course code already exists, please 
try again.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter the title for the course: ");
                courseTitle = scan.next().toUpperCase();
                entriesChanged = st.executeUpdate("Insert into Course values 
('" + courseCode + "','" + courseTitle + "')");
                System.out.println("You just added " + entriesChanged + " 
entries to the course list.");
            }
            rs.close();  //**********Closed the result set in this function.
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error during runtime, Error: " + 
e.getMessage());
        }
```

Here is my connection statement that I share through the Driver.java class:

```
try (Connection conn 

=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
"system", Chicken1") //connect oracle
                ) { 
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```

When I said "it locks up", I meant that it asks for the user to enter the title of the course once you enter a course code that already existed on the pre-written SQL table and then it just lets you type endlessly in the console without continuing the program.

However, if I add a course that does NOT exist on the pre-written table, then it adds it to the database and will not let me re-enter the course code that I entered already.

However, when trying to make the program stop me from entering a course code that exists on the pre-written SQL table, that is when it "locks up".

Comment: What do you mean by "lock up"? Which exception gets thrown? Does an exception get thrown? How do you create your Statement object?

Comment: @schmidi000 I updated the question with more information.

Comment: I had to chop the snippet into sections so it would fit in the dialogue box

Comment: Do some of your course titles have whitespaces in them?

Comment: Yes, almost all of them

Comment: Try scan.nextLine() instead of scan.next(). The method next() reads until the first whitespace occurs. It almost sounds like an input problem to me.

Comment: The program still stops running even though I use the nextline method, it's like it has issues with the pre written sql or something

Comment: Do you have some kind of loop in your program for your input? And does it print something after input?

Comment: Other than the question before the input no, and the only loop is the main programs loop.

Comment: And just a hint: A method should only do one thing. Your addCourse method reads from the command line, adds a new course and checks if a course does exist. Normally you would pass your course title or course object as an argument to your addCourse method, create a PreparedStatement in it and add the course. Then you would create a separate method to check if a specific course does already exist.

The input would be done in the main program.

Comment: Okay and what happens in your main programs loop? Because if you want to enter another course title after entering one, you have to put your scan.next() line in a loop.

Comment: That not the issue, the issue is it will not continue or give the println that there's a value already in the table if it was in the prewritten SQL

Comment: I put in a value that was already written in, then it asks for a title and it stops working

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` to show what you are reading from the console before using it in the SQL. My guess is you are reading something bad from the keyboard.